# Immediate Window automatic cleaning in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, immediate-window

I have a question about debugging in Visual Studio. Is it possible to clear the Immediate Window in Visual Studio automatically before each startup of a debugged application? The `>cls` command and `Context Menu->Clear All` are useful, but they are not automatic and require personal attention each time I run the application. Again, `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()|Write*()`  methods can only write messages to the Immediate Window, so `>cls` is not applicable. Is there any solution for the problem? (Currently I use VS 2008)

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the macro that does it. In the Macros IDE Class View navigate to MyMacros - EnvironmentEvents. Open (double-click) EnvironmentEvents. Insert the following code inside module:

```
Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildDone( _
    ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, _
    ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) _
    Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone

    Try
        Dim activeWin As Window = DTE.ActiveWindow
        Dim immedWin As Window = DTE.Windows.Item("{ECB7191A-597B-41F5-9843-03A4CF275DDE}")
        immedWin.Activate()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ClearAll")
        activeWin.Activate()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here you can see how it should look like:
[image: macro in EnvironmentEvents]

See my quick tutorial [how to create and execute VS macro](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/6?n=how-to-create-and-run-macro-in-visual-studio-net).

Comment: Thank you for reply, Peter. I've tried your code in VS Macros, but I've got an error _"Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types."_ in line *Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildDone* with BuildEvents object. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with VB.NET.

Comment: Did you place it in EnvironmentEvents module? There should be autogenerated region with correcr variable definition:
<System.ContextStaticAttribute()> Public WithEvents BuildEvents As EnvDTE.BuildEvents
Insert the macro after this region. I'll update mu answer with the screenshot

Comment: I've missed it at the ending of the work day. ))) Thank you, Peter! :)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and it only took 5 seconds go googling to find it. I can believe you only have one vote for this.

Comment: that should have been can't believe.